# Python path-breaking script for use in R

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x, file-system, r

R does not support line continuation as Python, and it's disturbing to have long file paths like

> /media/user/data/something-not-very-important-but-super-long/some-curious-secret-file.pdf

and can't break it into multiple lines.

The workaround is to use the file.path function:

```
file.path(
  "/root",
  "folder",
  "file.ods")
```

Manually editing is tedious, so here is a Python script that does the job for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

x = sys.argv[1]
# split by unix path separator
y = x.split("/")
# get rid of empty strings
y = [i for i in y if i]

# preserve / if it's an absolute path
if x.startswith("/"):
    y[0] = "/" + y[0]

# quote everything
y = ["'" + i + "'" for i in y]

res = "file.path(" + ",\n    ".join(y) + ")"
print(res)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always throw things in `main`:

```
def main():
    # code

main()
```

It might seem pointless but it does help with preventing global pollution, which is good if you ever decide to add a function somewhere.

Using

```
x = sys.argv[1]
```

is acceptable for a trivial script, but it's not much harder to use [`docopt`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docopt) and implement a proper command-line parser:

```
"""
Name Of Program.

Usage: prog.py <pathname>
"""

import docopt

def main():
    args = docopt.docopt(__doc__)

    x = args["<pathname>"]
```

Trivial, but it gives you `--help`, error reporting and sane handling of bad input, nearly for free.

This can be simplified a little with `pathlib`:

```
parts = pathlib.PurePosixPath(args["<pathname>"]).parts

if len(parts) >= 2 and parts[0] == "/":
    parts = ("/" + parts[1],) + parts[2:]
```

You can actually use just `pathlib.Path` but it may assume a Windows format on Windows machines.

Your quoting:

```
parts = ["'" + i + "'" for i in parts]
```

should be done with `repr`:

```
parts = map(repr, parts)
```

and the formatting should use `.format`:

```
res = "file.path({})".format(",\n    ".join(parts))
```

This gives

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
Name Of Program.

Usage: prog.py <pathname>
"""

import docopt
import pathlib

def main():
    args = docopt.docopt(__doc__)
    parts = pathlib.PurePosixPath(args["<pathname>"]).parts

    if len(parts) >= 2 and parts[0] == "/":
        parts = ("/" + parts[1],) + parts[2:]

    args = ",\n    ".join(map(repr, parts))
    print("file.path({})".format(args))

main()
```

Technically PEP 8 says `docopt` should be separated from `pathlib`, the second being in the stdlib, but it looks nicer this way for now.

Answer (score 2):

This seems quite alright. I have a couple of tips though:

- Since you use the `/` in multiple places, it would be good to give it a name.
- The variable names could be improved: `x` and `y` don't tell much about what they are.
- Instead of `"'" + i + "'"`, it's shorter and perhaps easier to read as `"'%s'" % i`, though the new style formatting is recommended, so this latter should be written as `"'{}'".format(i)`

Putting it together:

```
# use unix path separator
separator = '/'

origpath = sys.argv[1]
parts = origpath.split(separator)

# get rid of empty strings
parts = [item for item in parts if item]

# preserve / if it's an absolute path
if origpath.startswith(separator):
    parts[0] = separator + parts[0]

# quote everything
parts = ["'{}'".format(item) for item in parts]

res = "file.path(" + ",\n    ".join(parts) + ")"
print(res)
```

Comment: ["Since you use the `/` in multiple places, it would be good to give it a name."](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aa46e8db098dcbd3b428) Not sure I agree 'bout that. Also, new style formatting rulez: `"'{}'".format(item)`.

Comment: @Veedrac replacing a magic string literal with a well-named variable is certainly a good thing. You seem to miss the point with the gist, which would only be marginally related if I had named the variable `forward_slash`. You're right about new style formatting though, updated that in my answer